# Show image EXIF info

Tags: images

I am working on image gallery site. On test site (which is on shared hosting) I created and tested theme and plugins. I know that WP store some extra info about image during image upload (EXIF/IPTC fields) and I use them in my theme.
On image.php template I use this to show that info like this:

```
<?php
$imgmeta = wp_get_attachment_metadata($id);
echo '<div class="image-meta">Camera model:<br>'.$imgmeta['image_meta']['camera'].'</div>';
echo '<div class="image-meta">Aperture:<br>f/'.$imgmeta['image_meta']['aperture'].'</div>';

// ... similar for other image meta
?>
```

It works fine on test installation (shared hosting), but on production site (good VPS) not. I tried to reinstall WP, add/remove plugins. Also I tried to clone SQL from shared to VPS, and also with new clean install of WP on VPS without any plugin, but nothing.
From some reason WP on VPS do not show EXIF info.

What could be the problem? I guess it is server related, maybe something is missing from php modules or something? I put phpinfo on both servers, on shared hosting php version is 5.2.17 on VPS 5.4.27.

Comment: Have you checked the data actually exists? Is the `Exif` module for PHP enabled on your VPS?

Comment: Yes, image(s) are with EXIF data. When I upload image(s) on shared hosting I have that EXIF info, but with that same images uploaded on VPS like there is no any EXIF info inside images. I even downloaded images uploaded to VPS to see and confirm that EXIF is still there. How and where I can see if Exif module for php is enabled on my VPS. Thank you @TheDeadMedic

Comment: Just create a PHP file with `<?php phpinfo() ?>`, upload it and view it in a browser. This will show your complete PHP config. If you can't find any mention of `Exif`, [it's not installed](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=php+enable+exif).

Comment: On shared hosting I have "EXIF support enabled", "EXIF Version 1.4", "Supported filetypes JPEG,TIFF". But on VPS I can't find any mention of Exif. I will contact support to enable Exif module for PHP. Thank you.